# How to use jest/ react testing library to test if component is visible?

Tags: javascript, react-testing-library, ts-jest

I want to practice unit test so I created a book store with a variety of components. So I have a `relatedBooks` component for a react native app that is in a `bookDetailsRelatedBooks` component. In that component, I have this code below I want to write a unit test to cover.

```
{relatedBooks.map((relatedBook, index) => (
        <React.Fragment key={relatedBook.bookId}>
            <Grid item>
                <ViewabilityTrackingView
                    enabled
                    offsetBottom={150}
                    accessibilityState={{disabled: true}}
                    onViewabilityChange={({ isInView }: OnViewabilityCallbackParameters) => {
                        if (isInView) {
                            trackRelatedBookImpression(relatedBook.bookId, relatedBook.title, originBookId, index);
                        }
                    }}
                > 
                    <RelatedBookRow 
                        book={relatedBook} 
                        onClick={() => {
                            trackRelatedBookClick(relatedBook.bookId, originBookId, index); 
                        }} 
                    /> 
                </ViewabilityTrackingView> 
            </Grid> 
            <Grid item cx={styles.divider}> 
                <Divider /> 
            </Grid>
        </React.Fragment> 
    ))}
```

I tried this below but it does not work:

```
import { act, render, fireEvent } from 'react-testing-library';

test('trackRelatedBookImpression is called with correct arguments', () => {
  const relatedBooks = [{ bookId: 1, title: 'Test Book 1' }];
  const originBookId = 2;
  const trackRelatedBookImpression = jest.fn();

  const { getByTestId } = render(
    <bookDetailsRelatedBooks relatedBooks={relatedBooks} originBookId={originBookId} trackRelatedBookImpression={trackRelatedBookImpression} />
  );

  const viewabilityTrackingView = getByTestId('viewability-tracking-view');

  act(() => {
    fireEvent.scroll(viewabilityTrackingView);
  });

  expect(trackRelatedBookImpression).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1, 'Test Book 1', 2, 0);
});
```

I expected it to work but I got an error stating:

```
Found multiple elements with testID: viewabilityTrackingView
```

I tried assigning a `testId` to the `viewabilityTrackingView` but that does not work either, so I'm a bit stuck.